# How to capture a file name when using unzip -c and doing multiple greps

Tags: linux, grep, unzip

I am running the following command:

```
for file in 2017120[1-9]/54100_*.zip; do unzip -c "$file" | grep  "3613825" | grep '3418665'  ; done
```

This does a grep job of pulling the data that matches my grep parameters, but I can't figure out how to capture which file the results came from.

I have tried adding grep -H but the result comes back with (standard input).

How can I capture the file name?

Comment: What do you mean by 'capture' ?

Comment: Is the grep supposed to look in the files or at the filenames themselves? Also, as @GillesQuenot asked, what does capture mean, and what do you want your output to look like? Can you show us what it looks like now?

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do something like this I just add an `echo` of the file name to the `for` loop like this:

```
for file in 2017120[1-9]/54100_*.zip; do echo $file; unzip -c "$file" | grep  "3613825" | grep '3418665'  ; done
```

This prints out the list of files, and the grep line that matches will print immediately after the file that the match is in. like this:

```
file_1
file_2
file_3
matching line
file_4
file_5
another matching line
file_6
...
```

Thus I know the matching lines occurred in `file_3` and `file_5`.